# How to prove lower and upper bound for exponential sum?

Tags: inequality, summation

A paper I'm reading implicitly uses the fact $$\sum\limits_{t=1}^n e^{-ta^2} \in \theta(\frac{1}{a^2})$$ (It uses the both $\leq$ and $\geq$ sides in the proofs). I'm able to prove that $\sum\limits_{t=1}^n e^{-ta^2} \leq \frac{1}{a^2}$ by bounding the summation using integral. How can I prove $$\sum\limits_{t=1}^n e^{-ta^2} \geq c\frac{1}{a^2}$$ for some constant $c$?

Answer (score 2):

By the geometric series:
$$ \sum_{t=1}^n e^{-t a^2} = e^{-a^2}\frac{1-e^{-na^2}}{1-e^{-a^2}} $$
If $a$ is very large, this is approximately $e^{-a^2}$, and there is no way this is bounded below by $c/a^2$.  And if $a$ is very small, this is approximately $n-1$ - again no way is this bounded below by $c/a^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I too went through essentially the same argument. http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v30/Bubeck13.pdf is the paper I'm referring to (Page 8, thm 5, last step).